# Google maps combined with ArcGIS

Tags: google-maps, arcgis, arcgis-server

I'm trying to make a google maps view with a ArcGIS layer above it.

This works, but I get lot's of errors that they couldn't find some tiles.
But I think in the original ArcGIS layer these tiles don't exist.

Does someone know what I do wrong?

Thnx

Comment: This looks like a question better suited to [**GIS Stack Exchange**](http://gis.stackexchange.com)

Comment: I agree with @PolyGeo, however, we need more info than what is provided.  Please post your code (via jsfiddle) or a link to you web site where the code is running.

Comment: Ok will post code tomorrow ;)

Comment: I created a normal google maps with the V3 API and I posted the following code on it (this is the ARCGIS layer) But it gives errors of tiles that don't exist. 

http://jsfiddle.net/T5Qz2